# COMMA_TO_TABLE input value itself has Comma. comma-separated list invalid near pe(c_

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can any one help me with below issue. Below is my requirement.

My table format:

```
101    a
102    b
103    c
104    data_get.cust_val(data_get.cust_val(val_2),emp_id)
105    d

dbms_utility.comma_to_table
   ( list   => regexp_replace('100,a,101,b,103,c,104,data_get.cust_val(data_get.cust_val(val_2),emp_id),105,d','(^|,)','\1X')
   , tablen => l_count
   , tab    => l_array
   );
```

Currently 104 value is not taking up as the corresponding value has inside `COMMA (,)` and code consider that as well. How exclude those set of char values continue with next `COMMA (,)`?

> ERROR: comma-separated list invalid near al(d_..

Comment: COMMA_TO_TABLE is a procedure for parsing lists of database identifiers. Attempting to use it in this manner is just a blatant abuse, justly punished with failure. Don't try to fix it; you won't be able to. You need a generic way to parse arbitrary comma-separated strings. Then: there is NO utility that can work with an input string like you have. If comma is the separator, then any "literal" comma in the values must be escaped through *some* mechanism. This is not something that a parser, **any** parser, can fix; it must be fixed at the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values like `100` and `data_get.cust_val(data_get.cust_val(val_2),emp_id)` are not [valid Oracle identifier names](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm), which is what `dbms_utility.comma_to_table` is designed to parse. They cannot start with a number, contain brackets, exceed 30 characters etc.

Your `regexp_replace` turns this string

```
100,a,101,b,103,c,104,data_get.cust_val(data_get.cust_val(val_2),emp_id),105,d
```

into

```
X100,Xa,X101,Xb,X103,Xc,X104,Xdata_get.cust_val(data_get.cust_val(val_2),Xemp_id),X105,Xd
```

which handles the numeric names, but item 8 is still not a valid identifier.

If you are trying to parse a comma-separated string into an array, you will need to write your own utility.

Comment: I think i need to rephrase my question. It not an identifier. My REGEXP_REPLACE convert my input string as .. X100,Xa,X101,Xb,X103,Xc,X104,Xdata_get.cust_val(data_get.cust_val(val_2),emp_id),X105,Xd......... IT should not consider the COMMA inside this value.. data_get.cust_val(data_get.cust_val(val_2),emp_id)... Can you please help how to compose the pattern to perform like this?

Comment: By “compose the pattern” do you mean “write a function”? You can’t do this with `dbms_utility.comma_to_table`, or any other Oracle built-in.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be something more like "How to parse this comma-separated string" rather than "dbms_utility.comma_to_table is not working".